# Connect Oracle Server using VB.Net ODBC Issue

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I want to connect a an application which will run on Child system to Oracle server. Please guide.

Oracle is installed on Child System ver 11.1.0.6.20

Code:

```
Dim oracle_db As String = "Dsn=orcl;uid=se;pwd=se"
Dim oracle_con As New Odbc.OdbcConnection(oracle_db)
Dim dr As Odbc.OdbcDataReader
```

This is working on Server but could not connect via Child system.

sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora are copied from server to child also.

please

Comment: please post your tnsnames.ora if nothing confidential in it.

Comment: Oh and did you create the DSN orcl in the ODBC config screen ? (which is linked to the tnsnames.ora since you'll have to specify the server but has nothing to do with it)